# Dynamically Changing Theme of a view controller from another view controller without reloading

Tags: ios, swift

I have a "ViewControllerA" [VCA] and a view that slides into view when swiped (A hamburger menu?). It's ViewController is "ViewControllerB"[VCB]

I use this library to implement the side drawer 
https://github.com/dekatotoro/SlideMenuControllerSwift

What I want to achieve is that upon clicking on the button on VCB (after it slides onto VCA) the theme of the pages change. So I want update the colours of multiple elements.

How do I change the colours of elements in  VCA  without dismissing/reloading either controllers?

Some screenshots
[image: Blue background is VCA]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve your desired result you can go with `NotificationCenter`

Add an observer to the `ViewController` where you would like to get the event of theme changed (in your case it will be A)

`NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.themeChanged), name: "your_notification_name", object: nil)`

Add a method to handle the event of a post notification

`@objc func self.themeChanged(notification: NSNotification){
    //Your code
}`

Post the notification once you taped on the theme change button from another ViewController (in your case it will be B)

`NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("your_notification_name"), object: OBJ_TO_BE_SEND)`

**IMP : Please don't forget to remove the observer if it keeps adding**

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have a question What would be the OBJ_TO_BE_SEND in the object parameter?

Comment: OBJ_TO_BE_SEND is the `sender` of the notification. you can find more about `NotificationCenter` here... https://learnappmaking.com/notification-center-how-to-swift/

Answer (score -2):

This framework is making use of embedded view controllers. What you need to do is add a property called `VCA` of type `ViewControllerA` to `ViewControllerB`'s class:

```swift
class ViewControllerB: UIViewController {
    var VCA: ViewControllerA!
}
```

Then, in `ViewControllerA`, you need to implement `prepare(for segue:)` so that, when ViewControllerB is initialized, you set its `VCA` property so that `ViewControllerA` is stored as `ViewControllerB`'s `VCA`.

```swift
class ViewControllerA: UIViewController {
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let VCB = segue.destination as? ViewControllerB {
            VCB.VCA = self
        }
    }
}
```

Then, whenever clicking the theme button on `ViewControllerB`, you need to reference `VCA` and change its properties:

```swift
class ViewControllerB: UIViewController {
    var VCA: ViewControllerA!

    @IBAction func themeButtonPressed(_ sender: Any?) {
        if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "DarkThemeOn") {
            //Set the background color to light for both the menu VC and VCA
            view.backgroundColor = .white
            VCA.view.backgroundColor = .white
        } else {
            //Set the background color to dark for both the menu VC and VCA
            view.backgroundColor = .black
            VCA.view.backgroundColor = .black
        }

        //Toggle the theme
        UserDefaults.standard.set(!UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "DarkThemeOn"), forKey: "DarkThemeOn")
    }
}
```